# Setting exit code in atexit callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, atexit

Is there any way to set exit code in the function registered in `atexit` module and called on exit? The call to `sys.exit(code)` produces an error and does not set exit code to the desired value.

```
d:\>python atexit_test.py
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "atexit_test.py", line 3, in myexit
    sys.exit(2)
SystemExit: 2

d:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

The contents of `atexit_test.py`:

```
def myexit():
  import sys
  sys.exit(2)

import atexit
atexit.register(myexit)
```

Comment: What Python version is used? I can reproduce it on Python 3.5.1, but it works fine (both `sys.exit` and raising `SystemExit`) in Python 2.7.10. Can you use correct tag (python-2.x or python-3.x)?

Comment: @Rogalski I am using Python 3.5.1.

Comment: I'm using python 3.8 and I can confirm `sys.exit(code)` does not set exit code correctly. But one workaround is to use `os._exit(code)` which can set the desired exit code. Feel free to give it a try.


I understand that `_exit` should typically used in the child process after a fork. But considering https://bugs.python.org/issue27035 is still open and I need to make the atexit callback set the correct exit code so my CI can catch the failure, this is the only workaround that I find.

Comment: @iefgnoix Thank you for investigating this! I am not working on that project anymore but your comment answers my original question, so feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can prove the test code works in Python 2.7.x (2.7.6 in my case), as [reported by @Łukasz Rogalski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178636/setting-exit-code-in-atexit-callback#comment61891660_37178636). So I’ve assumed this to be a bug of Python 3.x and filed a [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue27035).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python 3.8 and I can confirm `sys.exit(code)` does not set exit code correctly. But one workaround is to use `os._exit(code)` which can set the desired exit code. Feel free to give it a try. I understand that `_exit` should typically be used in the child process after a fork. But considering https://bugs.python.org/issue27035 is still open and I need to make the atexit callback set the correct exit code so my CI can catch the failure, this is the only workaround that I find.

Comment: Note that this will break any `atexit` handlers that were registered before your handler (they're executed in LIFO order), because `os._exit` will hard-kill the program before they can be run.